# Find/Match every similar words in word list in notepad++

Tags: regex, find, notepad++, match

1. I have a word list in alphabetical order.
2. It is ranked as a column.
3. I do not use any programming languages.
4. The list in notepad format.
5. I need to match every similar words and take them on same line.
6. I use regex but I can't achieve correct results.

**First list is like:**

```
accept
accepted
accepts
accepting
calculate
calculated
calculates
calculating
fix
fixed
```

**A list I want:**

```
accept    accepted   accepts    accepting
calculate calculated calculates calculating
fix       fixed
```

Comment: That is really vague. How many of the first characters should be similar?

Comment: And should it only be leading characters? (e.g. is "boat" similar to "coat"?) Without a precise definition of what it means for two words to be "similar", this is not particularly solvable...

Comment: list consist of a words of plural ,adjective form,adverb form(if they exist)I mean list is like: abash abashed abashes abashing.Delete appendixes and find similar

Comment: Unfortunately, in the English language, that's not any closer to the precise definition needed - are 'carnation' and 'cartographer' "similar"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, but you will have to do `Replace All` multiple times:

Find `(^(.+?)\s*?.*?)\R\2` and replace with `\1\t\2`. `. matches newline` should be disabled.

**How it works:**

It finds some characters at the start of line `^(.+?)`, then any linebreak `\R`, and those same characters again `\2`.

`\s*?.*?` is used to skip unnecessary characters after multiple `Replace All`. `\s*?` skips the first whitespace, and `.*?` any remaining chars on the line.

Match is replaced with `\1\t\2`, where `\1` is anything matched in `(^(.+?)\s*?.*?)`, and `\2` is anything matched with `(.+?)`. `\t` is used to insert tab character to replace linebreak.

**How it breaks:**

Note that this will not work well with different words with similar prefix, like:

```
hand
hands
handle
handles
```

This will be `hand hands handle handles` after 2 replaces.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine doing this programatically with limited success (take first word which comes as a root and **if** derived word with this root follows, place it on the **same line**, **else** take the word as a new root and put it to **new line**). This will still fail at irregular words where root is not the same for all forms.

Without programming there is a way only with (manual) preprocessing – if there are less than 4 forms for given word in the list, you insert blank line for each missing verb form, so there are **always 4 lines** for each word. Then you can use regex to get each such a quadruple into one line.